# How do I get the size of a string truncated by UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, nsstring

I need to find the on screen size (CGSize) of a string that will be drawn in a UILabel. I know that I can use:

```
-(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

To find the size that a string will be, however, it does not take into account the maximum number of lines that UILabel lets you specify.

To rephrase if my UILabel has numberOfLines set to 2, and it receives a long string that gets truncated, how do I find the size (CGSize) of the string that is going to be drawn by the UILabel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the font's `lineHeight` property and multiply that by the number of lines, then feed that in as the maximum height of the `constrainedToSize:` parameter. Something like the following:

```
UIFont *font = getFont();
CGFloat maxHeight = font.lineHeight * label.numberOfLines;
CGFloat maxWidth = getWidth();
CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:(CGSize){maxWidth, maxHeight} lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: The code I posted doesn't handle the case where numberOfLines is 0, so if that's a possibility you may want to do something like `CGFloat maxHeight = (label.numberOfLines > 0 ? font.lineHeight * label.numberOfLines : CGFLOAT_MAX);`

Comment: There was that, and the condition where "lineHeight" is only supported in 4.0 and up. Since I needed it to run in 3.2 and up, I used lineHeight by default, but if it didn't respond to lineheight, I used sizeWithFont:constrainToSize: with CGFLOAT_MAX width, and retrieved the height from that. Fun times!

Comment: @Saltymule The old name for `lineHeight` is `leading`. This property was deprecated in 4.0 in favor of `lineHeight` because it was misnamed (it didn't represent the leading of the font but rather the distance between baselines. The actual leading is this value minus `ascender - descender`). If you're supporting 4.0 and above, use `lineHeight`. If you're supporting 3.2, use `leading`. The only difference is in the name.